# VARMAX model in r | Fit VARMA model including exogenous variable

Tags: r, package, modeling, varmax

Working on VARX model and I want to include MA term here but I have not found any package in R to build VARMAX model. MTS package can be used to fit VARMA model but I want to include exogenous variables while fitting the model.

is there any R package available for VARMAX modeling? if not then any alternative for this?